# Why pycharm doesn't recognize the modules?

Tags: pycharm

[image]

There are few related questions asked earlier. But none has the right answers working for me. This issue i face always. Sometimes it recognises correctly and those red marks go away. sometimes not at all.I have installed the configparser and my runtime configurations point correct virtual machine.  But still pycharm points it in red colour. why?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the parent folder of the file `ConfigParser.py`
2. In the menu got to `Mark Directory as` > `Sources Root` and click it.

Comment: No it didint work..Buy why should we do that? so each and everytime when we add new python files, do we need to change that folder?

Comment: @Ratha It adds the folder in the Python Path and makes Pycharm aware of it.